# Migrations in mongoengine: InvalidId

Tags: python, mongoengine

I am working with mongoengine and trying to do a simple migration.  I have a field which I would like to migrate from being a StringField to a ReferenceField to another Object.  I planned on doing the migration by hand, first constructing the new object based on the string that comes from the old StringField and then setting it explicitly.

The problem is I cannot even access one of the top level documents anymore once I changed the field type.  Is it required to create a "dummy" field in the my document's class code as a placeholder for the new field?  This seems kludgy to me so I assume there is a better way?

Here is the error, which is because the field coming out of the DB (StringField) is not consistent with a reference field.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    149                 return queryset._get_as_pymongo(queryset._cursor.next())
    150             return queryset._document._from_son(queryset._cursor[key],
--> 151                                                 _auto_dereference=self._auto_dereference)
    152         raise AttributeError
    153 

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/base/document.pyc in _from_son(cls, son, _auto_dereference)
    568                 try:
    569                     data[field_name] = (value if value is None
--> 570                                         else field.to_python(value))
    571                     if field_name != field.db_field:
    572                         del data[field.db_field]

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/fields.pyc in to_python(self, value)
    935            not isinstance(value, (DBRef, Document, EmbeddedDocument))):
    936             collection = self.document_type._get_collection_name()
--> 937             value = DBRef(collection, self.document_type.id.to_python(value))
    938         return value
    939 

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/base/fields.pyc in to_python(self, value)
    390     def to_python(self, value):
    391         if not isinstance(value, ObjectId):
--> 392             value = ObjectId(value)
    393         return value
    394 

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bson/objectid.pyc in __init__(self, oid)
     88             self.__generate()
     89         else:
---> 90             self.__validate(oid)
     91 
     92     @classmethod

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bson/objectid.pyc in __validate(self, oid)
    192                     raise InvalidId("%s is not a valid ObjectId" % oid)
    193             else:
--> 194                 raise InvalidId("%s is not a valid ObjectId" % oid)
    195         else:
    196             raise TypeError("id must be an instance of (%s, %s, ObjectId), "

InvalidId: Was Dirty: a2111fe89383bb562738b81c2b63fe78e877ed32 is not a valid ObjectId
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always migrated things by hand using an intermediate collection or an intermediate field in the same collection, but [this example](https://gist.github.com/rozza/3379016) makes it look like you don't have to.  Stack overflow hates external links so I'm including the example verbatim below.  BTW be careful with that "drop_collection" part!

```
import unittest
from mongoengine import *


class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        conn = connect(db='mongoenginetest')

    def create_old_data(self):
        class Person(Document):
            name = StringField()
            age = FloatField()  # Save as string

            meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}

        Person.drop_collection()

        Person(name="Rozza", age=35.00).save()

        rozza = Person._get_collection().find_one()
        self.assertEqual(35.00, rozza['age'])

    def test_migration(self):

        self.create_old_data()

        class Person(Document):
            name = StringField()
            age = StringField()

            meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}

        for p in Person.objects:
            p.age = "%s" % p.age
            p.save()

        rozza = Person.objects.first()
        self.assertEqual("35.0", rozza.age)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2 options I would suggest for your migration script:

- using DynamicField on the field you must migrate should allow you to read ObjectIds and store back DBRefs
- doing the migration in pymongo directly (pymongo's collection is accessible through Person._get_collection()) and looping over the items, updating & saving