# Make MongoDB adapt to mongoengine documents

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Let's say for example I defined this document using mongoengine.

```
from uuid import uuid1
from mongoengine import Document, StringField, UUIDField
class ImageModel(Document):
    uuid = UUIDField(default=uuid1, required=True)
    current_version = StringField(default='0')
    latest_version = StringField()
```

So the first time I create a document using mongoengine, it will have these fields. If I delete a field from this class or change its type, an error will raise indicating that the field doesn't exist, that is because previous documents written to the database still have it.

Is there a way to make MongoDB documents adapt to the changes automatically using Mongoengine? I.e make it have the same fields as my classes and delete the ones that are no longer present.

Answer (score 0):

There are no migrations tools in mongoengine.
You have to write your own script.

Here are some interesting links :

- [Migrations in mongoengine: InvalidId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618863/migrations-in-mongoengine-invalidid)
- https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/2052

And there is a package [here](https://pypi.org/project/mongoengine-migrate/) but there is no stable version at the moment. So it would be risky to use it in production.